# change format of system date

Tags: iphone

i am trying to change my date from system.I am using NSdate to pick date from system and change the format.Can anyone tell me how to change the format of my system date?I am using nsdateformatter to change the date format.I want the dateformat to strip off all the timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the time style?

```
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full solution with GMT and NSString conversion too:

```
NSDate *time = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss MM-dd-yyyy"]; //you can play with this structure
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT-05:00"]];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:time];
NSString *strTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stringFromDate];
```